# angular get url without using a router

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get a parameter from the URL without having a router in the specific page. I've read that you can use $location.search().clearCart and that'll give the value of clearCart . I get undefined. Is there a way of getting this without using a router?

The url is: http://ec2-50-17-53-129.compute-1.amazonaws.com/home?clearCart=true

this is my controller:

```
    app.controller('cartCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $http, $location, dialogs, ngCart) {
        if(($location.search()).clearCart != 'undefined' && ($location.search()).clearCart == 'true'){
            for(var i = 0; i < ngCart.getTotalItems(); i++){

                ngCart.removeItem(i);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you put an example of your url and the output of $location.search() on your question ?

Comment: `$location.search()` returns an object which is a series of key:value pairs.  Have you tried logging `$location.search()` to the console to see if your key is in the object?

Comment: Do you want the value of the Query string parameter or the name of the parameter?

Comment: I tried to log $location.search() and it doesn't have "clearCart" in it. I also tried ($location.search()).clearCart and got undefined

Comment: @Dylan - I want the value.

Comment: So your basically asking how to get the value of a known querystring?

Comment: I am asking how to get the value of clearCart. it can either be true or do not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really an angular thing, but you can use it in your controller fine.

```
  var queryStringValue = GetQueryStringParams('clearCart');

    function GetQueryStringParams(sParam) {
        var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
            var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
            if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) {
                return sParameterName[1];
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have not injected $location dependecy correctly

You need to inject the dependency $location in order to use it.

Here is a post that solves your problem:

[Angular JS: $location injection undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19670220/angular-js-location-injection-undefined)

In it you can find this plunkr:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $location) {
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
    if (true) 
      $location.url("/login")
  })
})
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/gf5LhTjqhz4MoZfVcqIt?p=preview

Hope it helps :)